# Run an EXE as Administrator on windows domain PCs at login silently

Tags: windows, windows-domain, login-script

Is it please possible to run an EXE file under Administrator permissions automatically when a Windows domain (NON-Administrator account) user logs in, and if so, how would I do this?

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User

Comment: I've removed your code block as it is unrelated to your question; Running an executable with elevated permissions on login of a regular user

Comment: Well you probably have missed that the code was actually what the EXE does :-) I added the code in case someone understood what was in it and would be able to do it just in e.g. Powershell and windows registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create GPO policy with logon script that starts the your `.exe` file.

[image]

And the script should lock like this if it is Batch script:

```
"\\Share\YourApp.exe"
```

Or like this if it is a PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "\\Share\YourApp.exe"
```

Your application will be run with elevated premisions.

Comment: I almost downvoted because I'm already running through a GPO logon script, and there was _no way_ I hadn't already tested running the exe through it. Otherwise, why would I have been Googling for a workaround for all these hours?? Then I test it and it works. Oh brother.